# Найти собственный вектор стохастической матрицы с собственным числом 1

Tags: python, матрицы, вектор

Я решаю задачу из [acm.timus №1766](https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1766). Всё решение задачи сводится к расчёту стационарного вектора вероятностей из матрицы перехода. Составить стохастическую матрицу перехода не представляет труда, но у меня нет ни единой идеи как сделать алгоритм для нахождения её собственного вектора.
На данный момент есть код для обработки ввода и составления матрицы перехода:

```
markov = [[0] * 65 for i in range(64)] #Стохастическая матрица переходов
for i in range(8): #Получаем построчный ввод зелюков и создаём матрицу
    row = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    zeluki.append(row)

for i in range(8): #Создание стохастической матрицы
    for j in range(8):
        summ = 0
        for x in range (-1, 2): #Для каждой клетки поля считаем количество зелюков на соседних с ней
            for y in range(-1, 2):
                if x or y:
                    if i + x >= 0 and i + x < 8 and j + y >= 0 and j + y < 8:
                        summ += zeluki[j + y][i + x]
        for x in range (-1, 2):    #Для матрицы переходов считаем вероятность перехода из одной клетки на другую
            for y in range(-1, 2): #для чего делится количество зелюков на ней на сумму зелюков с соседних клеток
                if x or y:
                    if i + x >= 0 and i + x < 8 and j + y >= 0 and j + y < 8:
                        markov[i + j * 8][i + x + (j + y) * 8] = zeluki[j + y][i + x]/summ
```

В интернете я смог найти только подобное решение задачи, но этот код в последний столбец, в котором по идее и должен быть ответ, пишет числа равные 1/64:

```
def addTo(j, i, d):
    for k in range(65):
        markov[j][k] += d * markov[i][k]

for i in range(64): 
    markov[i][i] -= 1
    
for i in range(65): 
    markov[63][i] = 1
    
for i in range(64):
    normal = markov[i][i]
    for j in range(65):
        markov[i][j] /= normal
    for j in range(64):
        if i != j:
            addTo(j, i, -markov[j][i])

            
for j in range(8):
    row = ''
    for i in range(8):
        row += format(markov[i + j * 8][64], '.12f')
        row += " "
    print(row)
```

UPD:
Добиться верного числового ответа помогло возведение матрицы перехода в квадрат, но для успешной сдачи задачи не хватает быстродействия. Можно ли как то оптимизировать это решение или надо думать в другую сторону?

```
n = 9
while n > 0:
    markov = [[sum(e1 * e2 for e1, e2 in zip(row, column))
              for column in zip(*markov)]for row in markov]
    n -= 1
```

Comment: Метод прямых итераций? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: `markov[63][i] = 1` - зачем?

Comment: Каким алгоритмом вы ищите собственный вектор?

Comment: Иначе система однородна и тогда алгоритм даст тривиальное решение. Конкретно тут я пытался реализовать исключение Гаусса.

Comment: Исключение Гаусса будет давать большие ошибки. Возводите матрицу в квадрат, нормируйте столбцы и смотрите на любой столбец. Он будет сходиться к нужному результату.